# Firebase Hosting with Function Not Working Locally

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I created a simple dynamic firebase hosting with function, everything works fine when deployed but not when the page is served locally.
This is the log of `firebase serve`

```
i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5004

✔  functions: serveLandingPage: http://localhost:5001/zonaskripsi18/us-central1/serveLandingPage
```

As we see, there is no error logs in console nor in `firebase-debug.log` but when I open `http://localhost:5004` it shows `An internal error occurred while connecting to Cloud Function "serveLandingPage"`

This is the `firebase.json`

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "function": "serveLandingPage"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the screenshot:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question with your configuration from firebase.json.

Comment: hi Stevenson, I've added the firebase.json's content

Comment: Look at your cloud function logs. It might be depending on server only config/features.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has been having issues with its local server lately, just deploy it and then run it to test it

Answer (score 0):

If your functions project is typescript then you have compile the typescript to javascript file before serving the localhost.

```
cd functions 
tsc
```